# Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adapter that would work at 4K @60Hz

Tags: hdmi, mini-displayport, 4k-resolution

I have bought this Club3D Mini DisplayPort™ 1.2 to HDMI™ 2.0 4K60Hz UHD Active Adapter
BUT despite it's name I had to return it. After connecting my Samsung UHD smart TV to my Lenovo thinkpad T460 MiniDP the TV got crazy and colours quickly flashed over the whole screen. The only way to make it work was to manually lower the refresh rate to 30Hz.
Does anybody have any adapter on any kind of laptop and adapter that would push this resolution via MiniDP to HDMI? I haven't seen any other than this one which does not seem to work.

Comment: Sorry but product recommendations are off topic on SU.

Comment: It sounds more of a problem with the source not supporting outputing at 60HZ then a problem with the cable itself. The fact it worked at 30HZ tells me the problem, is the Thinkpad itself, doesn't support 4k @ 60HZ

Comment: I do not think it is off-topic at all, and here's why:  Obviously in this case, the cable IS the right cable, but there are other problems.  Understanding which interfaces do what with 4K is NOT trivial, but he isn't looking for a hardware recommendation per se, (like, should I buy the samsung model x or what brand.)

Comment: @DaaBoss I'd agree with you, if the question was worded differently. It should be something like "....adapter doesn't work at 4k 60HZ" instead of "what adapter would work"

Comment: Assuming my answer works for you and most people, maybe someone will come by and help improve your title and question.  @DavidPostill, want to help improve this question??

Comment: If anybody has such an adaptor then thery wil explicitly mark it with HDMI 2.0 as output. Also make sure that your  Samsung UHD smart TV supports HDMI 2.0 (older HDMI versions do not supprot 4K @ 60Hz).

Answer (score 0):

**(Note: This will ONLY be true if your HDMI supports HDMI version 2.0 or higher.)**

**Use a standard HDMI cable**
I presume the goal here is to simply make 4k work with your laptop, which is much easier than you think.

First, ignore the display port.  Very likely your regular HDMI output, using an **"ordinary" HDMI cable, will deliver great 4k** with all the bandwidth your 4k video card, and more data than any 4k video card can deliver.

**Back-story**
This might sound anecdotal, but I went through something similar.... I bought a mini-display port cable for my AlienWare laptop, after getting a shiny new $400 retail Samsung 4k 27" monitor,  The monitor came with a large DisplayPort cable and two HDMI ports I didn't use, which worked flawlessly with a desktop's DisplayPort. The mini looked like it would work, but was too tall to fit.  In fact, I had a Thunderbolt port instead, so I started learning how to make that work.

I learned however, I'd need a $100 retail dongle to split off two HDMI ports.  Then I could easily drive two monitors as well as my 4k internal laptop monitor.  Cool, but my original requirement was to simply make the 4k work properly.  My solution turned out to use the HDMI I already had on my laptop, and for $5, I had everything all working in 4K!  I did, however, now understand the nuances of Thunderbolt, DisplayPort, all the flavors of HDMI, 4k monitors, video cards and TVs.

(Note my Alienware specs: "Run 4K resolution content @60Hz using the new HDMI 2.0 port". @Vitas is correct that his Lenovo's HDMI is only version 1.0, or at least not 2.0's spec, and so this solution will **not** work for him.)

Comment: Thank you all guys, but it would have been much better if you googled this about my laptop before ;-) http://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad%20T460/ThinkPad_T460_Platform_Specifications.pdf
According to specs only MiniDP is capable of 4K @60Hz. HDMI works with fullHD 60Hz. The question was actually if ANYBODY has some kind of adapter that would work via MiniDP on any laptop. I will try asking on lenovo forums yet. Thanks

Comment: I corrected my answer, so now I believe that it is accurate for everyone.  @Vitas - I've still got my MiniDP if you are interested and can find a way to reach me.  Alternatively, I got educated (see above) by a company's hour long chat that not only makes cables, but can tell you what will certainly work for your make and model.

Comment: allright why can't I send a private message here to somebody?...

Comment: You can't directly, but you can look at someone's profile.  Usually there's enough information to easily make contact with one Google search.  You might have to infer an email address, but...